# Logic App JSON transformed in Visual Studio

Tags: json, visual-studio, azure-logic-apps

When I switch logic app mode in Visual Studio 2017 Pro from Designer View to Code View Visual Studio formats the JSON. Please see the sample below the following code:

```
{
    "id": "@{variables('recordId')}",
    "status": "started",
}
```

Transformed into the following:

```
"{\"id\":\"@{variables('recordId')}\",\"status\":\"started\"}"
```

From a functional perspective, both versions are working fine. I'd like to know what is the reason of this transformation? and which one should be preferred?

Answer (score 0):

his

```
{
    "id": "@{variables('recordId')}",
    "status": "started",
}
```

is user-friendly json view, it's just a text

and this

```
"{\"id\":\"@{variables('recordId')}\",\"status\":\"started\"}"
```

is a string, that u can use in a code. If u use config.json file an so on - u can use frist one. If u want to set some string in a code - u should use second one

slash '\' is a protection symbol to write quotes inside other quotes

Comment: Thanks for the response. In my opinion, in the first case the value is set to JSON object, in the other - value is set to string. I'd like to keep it as a JSON object, but VS changes it to string for the reason that is not clear to me.